# Allowing node creation/editing inside other node creation form

Tags: nodes

I have a custom content type *congress*, and inside the *congress* creation form, I want to allow the user to create and edit as many nodes as he wants of the custom type *event*.

How can I accomplish that? I've seen it's possible to create a field for selecting an existing node with [node reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) and [node connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeconnect) modules, but those do not allow me to create or edit nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using [Entity Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) as instead of node reference, there's the [Inline Entity Form module](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) that does what you want:

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent -> children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.), where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.